# Virtio win driver(virt-manager QEMU-KVM)

Tags: virtualization

First of all i would want to apologize if this is the wrong section to post but i don't know what's the right one. So anyways.

I have a windows 10 virtual machine in virt-manager(QEMU-KVM-OVMF-LIBVIRT) ( I include ovmf because it is booting into UEFI and NOT BIOS)
so i see people recommending the spice guest additions which i have installed and verified they work
also qemu guest agent is installed
virtio drivers are installed BUT in the .iso file which includes the drivers there are also .msi files. One is 64 bit and the other 32. I installed the 64 bit but i can't find anyone anywhere online even refairing two these .msi files so i would like to know if i did and if you ever heard of them and install them